# How I can declare that: new float[,][,] {???}

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, neural-network

I can't figure out how to declare that (for self-knowledge):

```
var x = new float[,][,] {???};
```

What I need is a 2dArray of 2dArray of float...

```
float[float[,],float[,]];
// or
float[[,],[,]];
```

maybe

```
new float[new float[,], new float[,]] {???};
```

I'm sure it's possible.. jagged or not... I need a solution ...
If the Intellisense of VS don't give a red underlined error under

```
new float[,][,]
```

that's tell me this exist in some way ...

---

I can accept a Collection alternative:

```
new Tuple<float[,], float[,]>();
```

Oh for the curious of you ... I need that for a LINQ.Zip() operation ... I want that return a value like if I zip ,to the Python style, two 2dArray together ... I tried this:

```
var x = this.Biases.Zip(this.Weights, (b, w) => new Tuple(new List<float[,](b), new List<float[,](w)));
```

and

```
var x = this.Biases.Zip(this.Weights, (b, w) => new Tuple(new List<float[,](), new List<float[,]()) = new Tuple<float[,],float[,]>());
```

where `this.Biases` is a `List<float[,]>` and same for `this.Weights`.

But those tries got me error due to `Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Tuple'`

> Yes, it's about NN. I know that exist libs like Accord.Net, that new
>   one from Microsoft CNTK, or TensorFlow, ... name it !!! I'm the kind
>   of guy that love to do it vanilla style from the language that I use;
>   less extern lib that possible (encourage me as a code'bro ;) )

I successed on this thing one step before (C#):

```
this.Weights = this.Sizes.Take(this.Sizes.Count - 1).Zip(this.Sizes.Skip(1), (x, y) => new int[] {y, x}).Select(layer => NNGA.Math.Random.Rand2DArray(-2f, 2f, layer[0], layer[1])).ToList<float[,]>();
```

where `this.Sizes = List<float[]>();`
and `Math.Random.Rand2DArray(float x, float y, int dim1, int dim2);` return a 2dArray of Random float between `x` and `y` (custom static function) of dimension `[dim1,dim2]`.
That give me the exact thing of (Python):

```
self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

where `sizes = []` and `np` as `Numpy`'s Python library.

Hey guys, I'm facing the "Convert Python to C#" ... "non-typed to typed" language   ;)
HELP!!!

Comment: Arrays need a size in .NET/C# when creating (ie. with `new`). No size was provided so the `new float[..]` is invalid. (The size is not required for the array *type*, only creation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell it the size...

```
var x = new float[3, 4][,];
```

That gives you a grid of 12 spaces for 2D arrays of floats. Each of the inner arrays can be any size you like.

Comment: "[..] any size you like [that must also be specified as it is created]"

Comment: Thank you, I never play with Jagged before and the way you show it with your explanation, I got it right way !